# Reading csv and writing to new csv based up on criteria in python

Tags: python, csv

I am looking for some pointers to do the following

Read the data from a sorted csv and create different csv files based on a criteria. My input file looks like below

```
Ip       Subnet            location
1.0.1.2  255.255.255.0    Argentina
1.0.1.3  255.255.255.0    Argentina
1.3.4.5  255.255.255.0    Belgium
1.2.4.5  255.255.255.0    Belgium
3.4.5.6  255.255.255.0    California
1.2.7.8  255.255.255.0    California
```

What I wanted is I should get a csv file for every location ( 3 files as per above input file)
When it is reading the input file..the moment it finds a different location it should start creating new file and write the data...and again it finds a different location it should switch to a new file

Any help in achieving above would be very helpful...or is there any other way of doing this?

Comment: Did you try anything to solve this? if yes then please show your code.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SO is not a code writing service, please show your coding efforts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following script should work. It will create a CSV filename based on the current country. It assumes your input log file is in standard CSV format:

```
import csv

with open('log.csv') as f_input:
    csv_input = csv.reader(f_input)
    headings = next(csv_input)

    country = ''
    f_output = None

    for cols in csv_input:
        if country != cols[2]:
            country = cols[2]

            if f_output:
                f_output.close()

            f_output = open(country + ".csv", "wb")
            csv_output = csv.writer(f_output)
            csv_output.writerow(headings)

        csv_output.writerow(cols)

    f_output.close()
```

So for example you will get a file called `Argentina.csv` with the following contents:

```
Ip,Subnet,location
1.0.1.2,255.255.255.0,Argentina
1.0.1.3,255.255.255.0,Argentina
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Martin.....it worked like a charm
Only thing I have changed is removed "headings = next(csv_input)"
and specified rows in place of that  "csv_output.writerow(rows)"...then it got headings in all the files...earlier I got 2nd row as teh heading in all files.